# Create a list of ViewPager: list items blank

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I want to create a list of `ViewPager`.

I'm using a `ListView` managed by an `Adapter`, in which is created a viewPager for each listview item.

Here's the main activity (that extends `FragmentActivity`):

```
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        titles = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"};
        descr = new String[]{"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"};
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        adp = new ListAdapter(titles,descr,fm,context);

        list.setAdapter(adp);
```

ListAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context c;
    String[] ts , ds;
    FragmentManager fm;
    List<Fragment> frags;
    Activity act;

    public ListAdapter(String[] _ts , String[] _ds , FragmentManager _fm ,Context _c){
        ts = _ts;
        ds = _ds;
        fm = _fm;
        c = _c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ts[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_pager, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.mPager = (ViewPager)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        frags = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        frags.add(FragmentItemList.newInstance(ts[position],ds[position], c));
        frags.add(FragmentItemDelete.newInstance(ts[position],c));
        ScreenSlidePagerAdapter ad = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fm,frags);
        viewHolder.mPager.setAdapter(ad);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager , List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        public ViewPager mPager;
    }

}
```

When i run the application, only the first item is created correctly, the others are blank, like following image

[image]

LogCat is giving me that error:

```
05-14 15:30:32.816: W/View(18767): requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{41f9e6f8 VFED.... ......ID 0,0-540,150 #7f070006 app:id/pager} during layout: running second layout pass
```

Usually that error is caused by ListView property fastScrollEnabled. I haven't set it, but i disabled it anyway, but the issue still remains.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Did you have any solution for this?